# Google Chrome CSS issues

Tags: css

I am currently having some CSS problems with Google Chrome. Slider is overlapping with the buttons on the right side.

My theme layout (CSS) works fine with Firefox, and IE but not in google chrome.  Something to do with margins and alignments I think.

Here's the link: http://tigerdm.com.au/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a WordPress question, but if you remove the width from #slideshow-wrapper on line 4 of gallery-slider.css it sort of fixes rendering.